# Can you OUTPUT INTO when joining tables at the same time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to join tables when deleting because my deletion criteria are in the other table:

```
DELETE I
FROM [ItemsTbl] I
    LEFT JOIN [DatesTbl] D ON I.[DateId] = D.[DateId]
WHERE D.[ItemDate] < @ItemDate
```

But I also want to capture what did I delete. This is however not allowed:

```
DECLARE @RemovedItems TABLE(
    [ItemId] INT,
    [ItemDate] DATETIME,
)

DELETE I
FROM [ItemsTbl] I
    LEFT JOIN [DatesTbl] D ON I.[DateId] = D.[DateId]
OUTPUT DELETED.[ItemId], D.[ItemDate] INTO @RemovedItems
WHERE D.[ItemDate] < @ItemDate
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: `OUTPUT` goes *before* the `FROM`, not after. You cannot, however, `OUTPUT` columns from tables other that the `deleted` pseudo table in a `DELETE` statement.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), since they tell you what order each clause may appear in.

Comment: Oh crap, what an oversight. Thank you!

Comment: @Larnu that limitation only applies to the `OUTPUT` clause when used with `INSERT`, for updates and deletes you can reference other tables. [Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=af6d1f0db0d144fd6bd1455d9f46e683). Worth noting though that if you have a 1-n join, then you won't get n results output, you'll get 1 with an arbitrary value from any of the n records on the other side of the join.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. As @Larnu pointed `OUTPUT` goes before the `FROM`, not after.

```
DECLARE @RemovedItems TABLE(
    [ItemId] INT,
    [ItemDate] DATETIME,
)

DELETE I
OUTPUT DELETED.[ItemId], D.[ItemDate] INTO @RemovedItems
FROM [ItemsTbl] I
    LEFT JOIN [DatesTbl] D ON I.[DateId] = D.[DateId]
WHERE D.[ItemDate] < @ItemDate
```

Happy days, Thank you.